# fully load new page before displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a mobile site that has a link to another website.  The other website can take a few seconds to load so instead of having the user see a white screen while the other page loads, I want to keep them on my site and show them a message or image while I wait for the other page to load in the background, once it's complete, I want to then show the new page.  How can I do this?

Comment: Does the link redirect to the external website or is it loaded via AJAX / iFrame?

Comment: Having a **link** to a page means just that there's a way to click through to the page. Do you mean to say that you're importing content into your page somehow?

Comment: It redirects.  I have a page in my app  that when the users hit it, it redirects them to another site but the problem is the other site can take a few seconds to load so the users get a white screen.  I want my site to say "don't worry, it's coming", etc and when the other site is loaded, have the page transition to the other site.

Comment: That's a fundamental browser behavior -- Opera Mini 6.1 on the BlackBerry platform lets the user continue interacting with the 'old' page while it loads the 'new' page -- including the ability to decide to load different content even while the operation is underway. Your users are familiar with the behavior of their browser, and if they want a different behavior, they may select a different browser. I'm not sure it's your place to try to circumvent that via JavaScript fiddling...

Answer (score 0):

In the `window.onload` event you can show the container that has the page's main content and hide the loading image/message. ( the container should be hidden by default with `display:none;`)